# Pick date from a ListView(JSON data) and show it as a Calendar

Tags: json, swift, listview, calendar, jtapplecalendar

I'm really new at swift. I'm working at a project to retrieve data from database as JSON and put it to a CalendarView.

For example Image ListViewCalendar:

[image: Image ListViewCalendar]

I Created a ListView that fetches data in JSON format to a ListView.

Is it possible to get this data as events and just on data calendar pick it will show up the event from that day?

I'm just trying to get above the ListView an CalendarView which picks up a Monthly View.

Is it possible to get this?

Sorry for the picture. I don't have enough reputation to show an image normally.
I'm using for now JTAppleCalendar Library.

Comment: JTAppleCalendar can create the 2nd image, and it can create the calendar that sits above the 3rd image. But as of now, it cannot yet create the first image. I have this as a future upgrade coming.